# Is it possible to run prolog from C#?

Tags: c#, prolog

I want to call a prolog program from C#. Is that possible?
I process the user input by c# and write into a file.  I then want to call a prolog program which uses that file, then I want to show the content of the file to the user by c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you don't want to link the two programs to a single binary but simply have one (C#) call the other (prolog) this can be done. And for any other language you can run on your computer too.

If you base your data exchange on files you need one file to send data from C#->prolog and perhaps a second one to return the result (prolog->C#)

You will find lots of examples to make C# call an external program here on SO (for example [Launching an application (.EXE) from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c))

If prolog does not allow you to pass the filename as parameter when you call it you will have to work with fixed filenames:

C# writes a request.txt
C# calls prolog program
Prolog reads request.txt and creates response.txt

[Reading from files](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse54) should be covered by the language, depending on the "dialect" even [reading command line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725670/parsing-command-line-arguments) should be.

Comment: the problem is I can not pass argument to prolog shell by process.arguments.

Comment: @signal107 I don't know much about prolog or which specific prolog version you use, but there should be a solution to this problem. Please have a look at my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SWI-Prolog, you should google [**SWI-Prolog interface to C# and F#**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.html)